# axios POST request to strapi image upload [Internal Server Error]

Tags: reactjs, axios, internal-server-error, strapi

I'm uploading an image to strapi using axios but the response is 500 error. However in Postman the request is 200

***POSTMAN***

[image: POSTMAN Request]

***AXIOS CODE***

```
let bodyFormData = new FormData();

      bodyFormData.append('files', this.state.avatar, this.state.avatar.name)
      bodyFormData.append('ref', 'user')
      bodyFormData.append('refId', getId())
      bodyFormData.append('field', 'avatar')
      bodyFormData.append('source', 'users-permmissions')

      axios({
        method: 'post',
        url: `${strapi}/upload`,

        headers: {
          'Content-Type': 'multipart/form-data',
          'Authorization': `Bearer ${withToken()}`,

          },
          data: bodyFormData,
      }).then(res=>console.log(res.data)).catch(err=>{console.log(err.response.data.message)})
```

what's supposed to be the issue here?

Here's part of the strapi user model

```
{
     "avatar": {
      "model": "file",
      "via": "related",
      "plugin": "upload",
      "required": false
    }
}
```

Comment: Can you show us how you declared the variable `strapi`?

Comment: @SydneyY I added the users model

Comment: @SydneyY I removed the `bodyFormData.append('field', 'avatar')` part then it works, however, I need that part to upload it to the users model

Comment: `data: JSON.stringify(bodyFormData)` and `"Content-Type": "application/json"`?

Comment: it returns 400 (Bad Request) id: "Upload.status.empty"
message: "Files are empty".

Comment: it turns out that by doing `data: JSON.stringify(bodyFormData)` the Request payload is empty

Comment: I can't find any docs for strapi endpoint `/upload`. It seems like each content type has an endpoint. Is the variable `strapi` `localhost:1337/avatar`? Docs about endpoints https://strapi.io/documentation/3.0.0-beta.x/content-api/api-endpoints.html#endpoints

Comment: @SydneyY [https://strapi.io/documentation/3.0.0-beta.x/plugins/upload.html#endpoints](https://strapi.io/documentation/3.0.0-beta.x/plugins/upload.html#endpoints)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The solution is to throw Axios in the trash. I struggled with this for a day of my life that I will never get back. There's a longish, years-old thread at https://github.com/axios/axios/issues/318 with people complaining about being unable to get multipart form uploads to work with Axios.

I switched to the `request-promise` module and got it to work within minutes, using the following simple code:

```
const fs = require("fs-extra");
const rp = require('request-promise');
let out = await rp({
    method: 'POST',
    uri: 'http://mystrapihost/upload',
    formData: {
        // Like <input type="text" name="ref">
        'ref': "customer",  // name of the Strapi data type, singular
        'field': "attachments", // a field named "attachments" of type "Media"
        'refId': "838e238949ewhd82e8938299e289e99", // strapi ID of object to attach to
        // Like <input type="file" name="files">
        "files": {  // must be called "files" to be "seen" by Strapi Upload module
            name: "myfile.pdf",
            value: fs.createReadStream("/path/to/myfile.pdf"),
            options: {
                filename: "myfile.pdf",
                contentType: 'application/pdf'
            },
        },
    },
    headers: {Authorization: 'Bearer myjwtgobbledygook123456'}  // put your JWT code here
});
console.log(out);
```

Enjoy!!

Answer (score 0):

```
    This is how I fixed it for Strapi v4

const onSubmitHandler = async (e) => {
        e.preventDefault();
        const formData = new FormData();

        formData.append('files', image);
        formData.append('ref', 'api::event.event');
        formData.append('refId', evtId);
        formData.append('field', 'image');

        const res = await fetch(`${API_URL}/api/upload`, {
            method: 'POST',
            body: formData,
        });

        if (res.ok) {
            imageUploaded();
        } else {
            console.log(res);
        }
    };
```